# Filtro de um array com Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Ótimo dia a todos!

Eu estou apanhando para um filtro onde não entendo o pq está retornando o seguinte erro no console:

"vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: vm.polos.filter is not a function"

Ocorre quando desmarco a checkbox "All"...

A estrutura está em um arquivo "app.vue" e o cód. é o seguinte...

Obs. Não posso deixar o **link do webService**, mas ele está retornando os valores certinhos, o problema é na hora de filtrar...

```js
import Axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
 name: "poloFilters",
 data () {
  return {
   title: "Polos",
   url: "link do webService",
   current: 0,
   polos: [],
   estados: '',
   selectedPolo: ['All'],
  }
 },
 computed: {
  filteredPolos: function(){
   var vm = this // vm = Vue Model
   var category = vm.selectedPolo

   if(category.includes("All")){
    return vm.polos
   }else{
    // Aqui da ruim 
    return vm.polos.filter((polos) => {
     var keys = Object.keys(polos)
     var matchFilter = false
     category.forEach((key) => {
      if(polos[key] === true){
       matchFilter = true
      }
     })
     return matchFilter
    })
   }
  }
 },
 mounted () {
  // Chamando os polos colhidos
  this.pluckPolos()
 },
 methods: {
  //colhendo os polos
  pluckPolos(current = 1){
   this.current += current  
   const self = this
   Axios.get(self.url, {params: {current: this.current}})
    .then(res => {
     self.polos = {...self.polos, ...res.data.polos}
     self.filterMap = _.map(res.data.polos, function(poloRes){
      return poloRes
     })
    })
    .catch(err => {
     alert("Erro de conexão, tente novamente.")
     console.log(err)
    })
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<template>
 <div>
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <br>
  <hr>  
  <label for="all"> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="all" v-model="selectedPolo" value="All"> All
  </label>

  <label for="graduacao"> 
   <input type="checkbox" id="graduacao" v-model="selectedPolo" value="graduacao"> Graduação
  </label>

  <label for="posgraduacao">
   <input type="checkbox" id="posgraduacao" v-model="selectedPolo" value="posgraduacao"> Pós
  </label>

  <label for="graduacao20">
   <input type="checkbox" id="graduacao20" v-model="selectedPolo" value="graduacao20"> Segunda Graduação 2.0
  </label>

  <label for="formpedagogica">
   <input type="checkbox" id="formpedagogica" v-model="selectedPolo" value="formpedagogica"> Formação Pedagógica
  </label>

  <label for="tecnico">
   <input type="checkbox" id="tecnico" v-model="selectedPolo" value="tecnico"> Técnico
  </label>

  <label for="idiomas">
   <input type="checkbox" id="idiomas" v-model="selectedPolo" value="idiomas"> Idiomas
  </label>

  <label for="cursoslivres">
   <input type="checkbox" id="cursoslivres" v-model="selectedPolo" value="cursoslivres"> Cursos livres
  </label>

  <label for="preparatorios">
   <input type="checkbox" id="preparatorios" v-model="selectedPolo" value="preparatorios"> Preparatorios
  </label>

  <ul>
   <li>Here we go!</li>
   <li v-for="p in filteredPolos" :key="p.id">{{p.nome}}</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="poloBox">
   <div v-for="p in polos" :key='p.id' class="pBox">
    <img :src="p.image" :alt="p.nome">
    <div class="theData">
     <h3>{{p.nome}}</h3>
     <small v-if="p.semipresencial" class="semiPresencial">{{p.semipresencial ? 'Aqui tem semipresencial' : null }}</small>
     <hr>
     <address>
      {{p.endereco}}{{p.complemento}} - {{p.bairro}}
      <p>{{p.telefone}}</p>
      <p>
       <strong>{{p.graduacao}} {{p.pos ? ' • ' + p.pos : ''}} {{p.cursosLivres ? ' • ' + p.cursosLivres : ''}} {{p.tecnico ? ' • ' + p.tecnico : ''}}</strong>
      </p>
      <hr>
      <a href="#" class="btn">CONHEÇA AGORA</a>
      <hr>
      teste... <br>
      {{p.classes}}
     </address>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma ajudinha nessa questão?

Obrigado dês de já!

Comment: Dentro de `pluckPolos ` estás a sobreescrever` self.polos = {...self.polos, .`...

Comment: @Sergio nessa parte, eu uso o `self.polos = {...self.polos, ...res.data.polos}` de forma proposital, pois eu acabo carregando mais polos... Então eu faço "self.polos = {... **ele mesmo** , ... **Mais uma lista** }"...
Complementando, toda vez que eu chamar `pluckPolos()` ele acrescenta uma lista nova.

Comment: Isso não te dá uma array... terias de usar `[...` e não `{...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graças a um colega do meu Job, consegui entender o que estava acontecendo...

O **vm.polos** não estava retornando um **array** e sim um outro objeto cujo as propriedades eram índices.

Só transformei o **vm.polos** em **array** e tudo fluiu...